# Javascript - disable scroll on page but allow a specific div

Tags: javascript

I wanted to disable page scrolling through keyborad but allow on a specefic div on a conditions.

I had added the following codes, which working fine.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
   // space, page up, page down and arrow keys:
   if([32, 33, 34, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1{
     e.preventDefault(); }
   }, false);
```

Now, I want a div inside the body called `price-list` in where I need to enable scroll through keyboard.

Comment: Please post some relevant HTML, or even better, a jsFiddle.

Comment: Or even better, a Stack Overflow Snippet! Its the document icon with `<>` in it!

Comment: Use `e.target` to determine if its a div that should be scrolled on.

Comment: hi SILENT can you give me an example?